# Is there any way to kill the pending Bluebird promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

In my application, I have the below situation:

-Promise x
-Redirect to a specific
-Callback from the promise X that render other content

I need to kill this promise X when it's redirected, is there any way to identify and kill pending promises before? (There are another situations with different promises, that's why I need to identify pending promises)

Thanks!

Comment: A JavaScript `Promise` contains no "cancellation" construct. You can simply choose to ignore the completion, but once a promise is started, whether it actually cancels if you ignore the completion is implementation-dependent, and usually for convenience of development it is not possible to cancel.

Comment: You may cancel the async call e.g. `.abort()` for an XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: You cannot "kill" a promise, a promise doesn't live. What you can do is try to kill the process that will eventually resolve the promise, but it depends a lot on the particular process for how to do that.

Comment: Please show us your code. I can't make any sense of what is happening why and where and in what order.